# Why functionalities runs sequentially even though they are being called asynchronously inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, closures, settimeout

I am creating a wrapper function which will take array of functions and executes every function in a parallel manner so thought of using setTimeout but still functions are running sequentially. I suspect it could be because of closure that is being used to call SetTimeout. But why does it matter since setTimeout is async anyway?

```
// some blocking functionality
var withDelay = function (a) {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime(), delay = 5000;
   while (currentTime + delay >= new Date().getTime()) {
   }
   console.log(a+"I am with delay");
}

// some non blocking functionality
var withoutDelay = function(a) {
   console.log(a+"I am with no delay");
}

var fnArr = [withDelay, withoutDelay]; //array of functions
var args = ["Hi,"]; // arbitrary params

for( var i=0; i < fnArr.length; i++) {
    var fn = fnArr[i];
    (function(f,arg) {
        return setTimeout(function(){ return f.apply(f,arg) },0);
    })(fn,args)
}
```

Expected output:

> Hi,I am with no delay
>
> Hi,I am with delay

but Actual output is:

> Hi,I am with delay
>
> Hi,I am with no delay

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-single-thread-handle-asynchronous-code-in-JavaScript try reading this, the browser pushes the async calls in a queue. Hence this sequential behaviour

Comment: That `while` loop inside of `withDelay` function will freeze browser, then both of functions gonna run. And because of the order you've specified in `fnArr`, `withDelay` gonna fire at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

JS runs on a single thread, Your function will not run parallelly. It will only run one at a time. Since you have scheduled both the functions with 0 delay as soon the first function from `fnArr` array viz. `withDelay` will run first. Only when this will complete its execution, the second function `withoutDelay` will start its execution. `setTimeout` will not guarantee your execution after provided interval, it is the minimum interval after which your function will execute. You can read more about `setTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

While loop doesnot delay a function you need to use setTimeout in your `withDelay()` and it working fine

```js
var withDelay = function (a) {
   setTimeout(() => {console.log(a+"I am with delay")},5000);
}
// some non blocking functionality
var withoutDelay = function(a) {
   console.log(a+"I am with no delay");
}

var fnArr = [withDelay, withoutDelay]; //array of functions
var args = ["Hi,"]; // arbitrary params

for( var i=0; i < fnArr.length; i++) {
    var fn = fnArr[i];
    (function(f,arg) {
        return setTimeout(function(){ return f.apply(f,arg) },0);
    })(fn,args)
}
```

An example to call functions in a line after delay. As asked by questioner.

```js
function func1(){
 console.log("Function 1 is executed");
 console.timeEnd('t');
}
function func2(){
 console.log("Function 2 is executed");
 console.timeEnd('t');
}
function func3(){
 console.log("Function 3 is executed");
 console.timeEnd('t');
}
let arrr = [
   {func:func1,delay:2000},
   {func:func2,delay:2000},
   {func:func3,delay:3000},
  ]
async function callWithDelay(funcArr){
 
 for(let func of funcArr){
  //just to see time in console not necesarry 
  console.time('t');
  //create a promise
  let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   //'promise' will resolve after the function inside following code will end 
   setTimeout(()=>
   {
    resolve();
    func.func();
   },func.delay)
  })
  //The code will not proceed until the 'promise' is resolved(func is excecuted);
  let x = await promise;
 }
 console.log("All the functions are excecuted");
}
callWithDelay(arrr);
```

Comment: but then its not blocking function anymore. It is just deferring the things. I may have any kind of function in queue (array) for execution.

Comment: @kish I have updated for answer. Is shows example of running an array of functions with time delay in a queue. With `Promises` and `async await`. Accept the answer if you are satisfied